Dell FX2S NVME compatibility
I have a DELL FX2S chassis with 2 FC630 compute nodes and 2 storage nodes.
I was wondering if we can migrate to a faster storage, and so was planning to either purchase a PCIE card to place in the compute nodes to add some U.2 or similar NVME disks, or purchase a PCIE card to place in the chassis and a mezzanine card which I believe is needed to passthrough the card from the chassis to the compute node.
Since this will be a first attempt, I was wondering if someone else has tried a similar configuration, so we can avoid purchasing something that isn't compatible with what we are trying to achieve.
I am also planning to do a similar attempt in a FX2S chassis with FC430 compute nodes. This one has no storage node, just the local storage of the compute node.
Ideally I would want the FC430/FC630 to have the disks at the front so they can be swapped easily, rather than being attached to the PCIE card itself. It is not a requirement, but I would rather remove a disk without having to shut down the compute node, instead of having to shutdown, disassemble the PCIE card and unscrew the disk that I need to replace.
Finally, I would ideally like the PCIE NVME card to have hardware RAID, at least RAID 1 but ideally support at least 4 disks and hardware RAID 10.
Answers with compatible brands / models of working configurations would be great :)
Thank you in advance for any valuable insight.
Just some additional notes based on my research:

I believe I need something like this card: https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/dell-poweredge-exp-fsh-pcie-ssd_User's%20Guide_en-us.pdf
And also a backplane: https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_dell_adapters/dell-poweredge-exp-fsh-nvme-pcie-ssd_user's-guide3_en-us.pdf

However, I am not sure if these are compatible with FC430/630 and the FX2s chassis.
Also, I would rather have a proper RAID card instead of just that expansion card DELL provides.
UPDATE November 1
Considering the first answer I received, I am providing some more details of the goal. I would like to have a RAID card on the chassis, forward that card to a compute node, and have RAID 10 on that node. The card could be something like this: https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-9660-16i
I also enquired Dell to know if we could just swap the PERC that exists in the storage node for one compatible with NVME, but we can't.

You can insert Dell-approved PCIe NVMe cards, but due to the limited number of PCIe slots, which is two per node tops for the quad-node configuration (see the link to the official Dell extension guide below in P.S.), you are restricted to an OS-level RAID1 for redundancy as your only option. Commercial software-defined storage solutions like VMware vSAN and Microsoft S2D require significantly more than just two storage devices per physical node. As a result, IBM Ceph and StarWind Virtual SAN remain your only viable options for internode replication.
P.S. “FX2s - PCIe Expansion Bus and Slot Reassignment Options”
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000135744/fx2s-pcie-expansion-bus-and-slot-reassignment-options

Hi. I am going to try and rephrase what you said to try and make something out of it :) Even if I have one single PCIe slot, I can put something like this in one of those slots and have RAID 10 in my node or am I missing something? https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-9660-16i
If this were to be the solution, I would need no OS level RAID, my other concern would be: how and where would I attach the drives onto. Am I looking at this the wrong way?
